# Which Aurora table store DAG variable information?

Tags: airflow, amazon-aurora, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an airflow DAG which call a particular bash command using a variable. At the backend, we have Aurora DB. Do we know if there are any tables in the Aurora DB which stores information of the variables used in Airflow DAGs? I need to create a report out of it and hence, the ask to access the variables from backend.

I tried using the operational_insights schema but could not find any tables with the desired information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an [Airflow variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html) you should be able to query a list of them with the [REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_variables) no matter which backend you use.

`curl "http://<your Airflow host>/api/v1/variables" --user "login:password"`

This is preferred over querying the Airflow metadata database directly because if you accidentally modify or drop a table you can corrupt your Airflow.

With that caveat: the standard table where Airflow variables are stored is `variable` so after logging into the db `SELECT * FROM variable;` should return a list.

Again this is for Airflow Variables. From your question I am not entirely sure if you mean that or in general any variables that tasks use. In the latter case you might be looking for the `rendered_fields` parameter of the task instances, which can also be done [using the API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_task_instance).

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I am here talking about Airflow variables only. Any chance you can share the schema name where I can see the variable table?

Comment: In my setup (standard setup with postgres) the schema name is `public`, unless your database uses a custom setup, you should also be able to find the `variable` schema there :)